# jQuery running code on input text box change

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code runs fine from the `#input-lines-percent` inputs and updates the values correctly. `#input-curves-percent` does run the code so the change seems to be working, but it's not updating the text boxes at all.

To see what I mean, type some text in the `Straight lines %` box and see how both text boxes update. However try this on the `Curves %` and there is no update. The code for both is almost identical, so I am not sure what is causing this difference.

```js
$('#input-curves-percent').change(function(e){
    updatePercentGroupShape('curve');
});
$('#input-lines-percent').change(function(e){
    updatePercentGroupShape('line');
});
function updatePercentGroupShape(lastEdit){
    // Updates the percentage boxes for the shape type percents
    
    var curves = parseInt($('#input-curves-percent').val());
    var lines = parseInt($('#input-lines-percent').val());

    if(lastEdit.localeCompare('curve') == 0){
        
        if(curves < 0){
            curves == 0;
        }else if(curves > 100){
            curves = 100;
        }
        lines = 100 - curves;

    }
    if(lastEdit.localeCompare('line') == 0){
        
        if(lines < 0){
            lines == 0;
        }else if(lines > 100){
            lines = 100;
        }
        curves = 100 - lines;
    }
    $('#input-curves-percent').val(curves);
    $('#input-line-percent').val(lines);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <div>Curves %</div>
 <div><input type="text" id="input-curves-percent" value="0"></div>
</div>
<div>
 <div>Straight lines %</div>
 <div><input type="text" id="input-lines-percent" value="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is that lastEdit.localeCompare('curve') is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo in last js line, just replace

```
    $('#input-line-percent').val(lines);
                 ^^^
```

with

```
    $('#input-lines-percent').val(lines);
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a typo error in it.

```
 id="input-lines-percent"
```

and in script

```
$('#input-line-percent').val(lines);
```